# Encoding issue in tidyverse startup message in RStudio: distorted UTF-8 output (<U+2713>)

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

Some time ago everything was ok. But after recent updates (I cannot track down which ones), in RStudio the "Attaching packages" section of the *tidyverse* startup message has encoding issues while the "Conflicts" part is correct. In R Gui this issue is not present (and there are no different colors).

How can I get a non-distorted *tidyverse* startup message in RStudio? (With `v` and not `<U+2713>`).
Is it a bug in some package or RStudio?
Are there some settings incorrect on my side?

[image]

Rstudio version: 1.2.5033

```r
> sessioninfo::session_info("tidyverse")
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       Europe/Helsinki             
 date     2019-12-17                  

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package      * version     date       lib source                             
 askpass        1.1         2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 assertthat     0.2.1       2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 backports      1.1.5       2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 base64enc      0.1-3       2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 BH             1.72.0-2    2019-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 broom          0.5.3       2019-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 callr          3.4.0       2019-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 cellranger     1.1.0       2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 cli            2.0.0       2019-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 clipr          0.7.0       2019-07-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 colorspace     1.4-1       2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 crayon         1.3.4       2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 curl           4.3         2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 DBI            1.1.0       2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 dbplyr         1.4.2       2019-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 digest         0.6.23      2019-11-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 dplyr          0.8.3       2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 ellipsis       0.3.0       2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 evaluate       0.14        2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 fansi          0.4.0       2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 farver         2.0.1       2019-11-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 forcats        0.4.0       2019-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 fs             1.3.1.9000  2019-12-14 [1] Github (r-lib/fs@cb8930f)          
 generics       0.0.2       2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 ggplot2        3.2.1       2019-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 glue           1.3.1       2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 gtable         0.3.0       2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 haven          2.2.0       2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 highr          0.8         2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 hms            0.5.2       2019-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 htmltools      0.4.0       2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 httr           1.4.1       2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 jsonlite       1.6         2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 knitr          1.26        2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 labeling       0.3         2014-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 lattice        0.20-38     2018-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 lazyeval       0.2.2       2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 lifecycle      0.1.0       2019-08-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 lubridate      1.7.4       2018-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 magrittr       1.5         2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 markdown       1.1         2019-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 MASS           7.3-51.4    2019-03-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 Matrix         1.2-17      2019-03-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 mgcv           1.8-31      2019-11-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 mime           0.7         2019-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 modelr         0.1.5       2019-08-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 munsell        0.5.0       2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 nlme           3.1-143     2019-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 openssl        1.4.1       2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 pillar         1.4.2       2019-06-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 pkgconfig      2.0.3       2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 plogr          0.2.0       2018-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 plyr           1.8.5       2019-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 prettyunits    1.0.2       2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 processx       3.4.1       2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 progress       1.2.2       2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 ps             1.3.0       2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 purrr          0.3.3       2019-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 R6             2.4.1       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 RColorBrewer   1.1-2       2014-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 Rcpp           1.0.3       2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 readr          1.3.1       2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 readxl         1.3.1       2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 rematch        1.0.1       2016-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 reprex         0.3.0       2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 reshape2       1.4.3       2017-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 rlang          0.4.2.9000  2019-12-13 [1] Github (r-lib/rlang@ec7c1ed)       
 rmarkdown      2.0         2019-12-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 rstudioapi     0.10.0-9003 2019-12-17 [1] Github (rstudio/rstudioapi@abe596d)
 rvest          0.3.5       2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 scales         1.1.0       2019-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 selectr        0.4-2       2019-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 stringi        1.4.3       2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 stringr        1.4.0       2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 sys            3.3         2019-08-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 tibble         2.1.3       2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 tidyr          1.0.0       2019-09-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 tidyselect     0.2.5       2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 tidyverse      1.3.0       2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 tinytex        0.18        2019-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 utf8           1.1.4       2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 vctrs          0.2.0       2019-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 viridisLite    0.3.0       2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 whisker        0.4         2019-08-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 withr          2.1.2       2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 xfun           0.11        2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 xml2           1.2.2       2019-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                     
 yaml           2.2.0       2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                     
 zeallot        0.1.0       2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Comment: I've got the same thing - tidyverse 1.3.0, RStudio 1.2.5019, R 3.6.2, Windows 10.  Everything seems to be working as normal, so I don't think it is affecting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to a bug in the `cli` package.
See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/211) and [here](https://github.com/r-lib/cli/issues/124).

The development version of `cli` resolved this, and you can install it by running `remotes::install_github("r-lib/cli")`.