# Why does R show me unicode symbols when loading library(tidyverse)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I had updated a few packages in R using the following command -

```
install.packages(c("BH", "DBI", "Matrix", "SparseM", 
                   "broom", "caTools", "callr", "cli", 
                   "curl", "data.table", "digest", "e1071", 
                   "foreign", "htmlTable", "igraph", 
                   "maptools", "multcomp", "nlme", "openxlsx", 
                   "plyr", "quantreg", "rmarkdown", "survival", 
                   "testthat", "tinytex", "vctrs", "webshot"))
```

After this, every time I load tidyverse library (using library(tidyverse)), I get the following output. Is any of the updated packages causing this? I cannot find any similar problem / solution online. I have not had this problem before.

Appreciate any input. Thank you.

```
    > library(tidyverse)
<U+2500><U+2500> Attaching packages <U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500> tidyverse 1.3.0 <U+2500><U+2500>
<U+2713> ggplot2 3.2.1     <U+2713> purrr   0.3.3
<U+2713> tibble  2.1.3     <U+2713> dplyr   0.8.3
<U+2713> tidyr   1.0.0     <U+2713> stringr 1.4.0
<U+2713> readr   1.3.1     <U+2713> forcats 0.4.0
<U+2500><U+2500> Conflicts <U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500><U+2500> tidyverse_conflicts() <U+2500><U+2500>
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: `U+2500` is the [Box Drawings Light Horizontal](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2500). When loading, package `tidyverse` displays a message with those characters, so maybe you should check your system's encoding.

Comment: See this previous question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379565/encoding-issue-in-tidyverse-startup-message-in-rstudio-distorted-utf-8-output

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you for the link. I did more reading and it is a problem of the 'cli' package. The issue has been corrected in the master branch on GitHub. I tried `remotes::install_github("r-lib/cli")` to get it. It downloads fine, but has an error while installing. This is on a Mac (El Capitan). Any thoughts?Last two lines on error:<U+2500>  building 'cli_2.0.0.9000.tar.gz'
   
Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"